# How to give HTTP traffic higher priority?

Tags: linux, networking, bittorrent

When I surf the web, I find that I have to pause my BitTorrent client, to help improve the painfully slow speed (I'm sadly on a 384kbps line). It's not too nice to have to do this manually *every* time.

Please show me the magic button, the one which I only need to press once in order to be blessed with speedier, higher-priority surfing, where the torrents speed take a backseat, only to resume to full speed once my web-surfing is over.

[**FYI**] NetworkManager manages my network, and Transmission is my BitTorrent client.

Comment: There's not a simple solution to this. Giving higher priority to http traffic will slightly improve things, but your best bet would be to just throttle your torrent client.

Answer (score 19):

As already said, there is no button "Give me fast surfing" somewhere on your desktop. What you want is traffic shaping which is possible with Linux.

For the complete introduction, you can read these tutorials:

- [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control](http://lartc.org/)
- [Traffic Control HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/index.html)
- [tc: Linux HTTP Outgoing Traffic Shaping (Port 80 Traffic Shaping)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/)

But I think you are searching for something more like these:

- [The Wonder Shaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/)
- [MasterShaper](http://www.mastershaper.org/)

These are scripts which will do the work for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to spend too much time configuring a traffic shaper, try the `transmission` builtin temporary speed limit feature (which can also be scheduled).

[image]

You can activate or deactivate it over the indicator applet.

Comment: This is what I do but the OP specifically mentioned in his post that he does not want to do this every time i.e., he is looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: The OP edited that in after my answer.

Comment: @6pack is correct. This was my requirement from the beginning (check the initial revision). I think I edited my question to make this requirement clearer (probably as a reaction to your answer).

Answer (score 4):

An alternative simple solution could be to use the QoS of your router (Quality of Service), this may allow you to give higher priority to certain protocols (i.e. HTTP/HTTPS).

If you don't have QoS on your router the only way are the one explained above.

One more link:

http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Fair_traffic_shaping_an_ADSL_line_for_a_local_network_using_Linux

Be aware that if you give high priority to HTTP or HTTPS, then, almost probably, your torrent won't work anymore, this is because many applications use the HTTP protocol to exchange data over the network, so there will be always something matching the iptable rule.

I'd rather advice to use a Command line version of bittorrent, like [rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/), this way you can write a simple shell script that will change the torrent download throttle and then execute firefox (or whatever).

You can also stop rtorrent downloading after certain conditions.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent
http://superuser.com/questions/180866/configure-rtorrent-to-stop-downloading-after-a-certain-file-size

http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/

Comment: Sadly, my router doesn't do QoS for wi-fi.

Comment: What if you don't have a router?

Comment: Has been answered above. Read thorough the whole thread.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy: don't saturate your upload, so limit your torrent client's upload limit to about 50% of your total upload bandwidth.

Comment: Is it possible to shape the download?